# Python 3: Getting IndexError: list index out of range on shuffle method

Tags: python

I'm building a blackjack command line game and I've run into a snag. The shuffle feature on my deck class object keeps coming up with IndexError: list index out of range on line 29.  It is a sporadic bug, id say about 50% of the time it comes up. 
Here is the code:

```
import random

#class constructor for cards
class card:
    def __init__(self, suit, card_name, card_value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.card_name = card_name
        self.card_value = card_value

#class constructor for the deck
class deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_deck = []
        self.suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds','spades','clubs']
        self.cards = ['ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','jack','queen','king']
    def initialize(self):
        for i in range(len(self.suits)):
            for j in range(len(self.cards)):
                if (self.cards[j]=='2' or self.cards[j]=='3' or self.cards[j]=='4' or self.cards[j]=='5' or self.cards[j]=='6' or self.cards[j]=='7' or self.cards[j]=='8' or self.cards[j]=='9'):
                    self.current_deck.append(card(self.suits[i], self.cards[j], int(self.cards[j])))
                elif (self.cards[j]=='10' or self.cards[j]=='jack' or self.cards[j]=='queen' or self.cards[j]=='king'):   
                    self.current_deck.append(card(self.suits[i], self.cards[j], 10))
                else:
                    self.current_deck.append(card(self.suits[i], self.cards[j], 11))
    def shuffle(self):
        for card in self.current_deck:
            j = random.randint(0, len(playing_deck.current_deck))
            temp = card
            card = self.current_deck[j]
            self.current_deck[j] = temp

class dealer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 10000
        self.hand = []
    def hit(self, deck_):
        self.hand.append(deck_.pop())
    def deal(self, deck_, player_):
        self.hand.append(deck_.pop())

class player: 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.money = 200
        self.hand = []
    def hit(self, deck_):
        self.hand.append(deck_.pop())

josh = player('josh')

playing_deck = deck()

playing_deck.initialize()
playing_deck.shuffle()

josh.hit(playing_deck.current_deck)


for i in range(len(playing_deck.current_deck)):
    print(vars(playing_deck.current_deck[i]))
```

Comment: Why not use `random.shuffle`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Well, `random.shuffle` actually randomizes the order; his function just swaps each card one time. If you're trying to simulate some physical process, that might make more sense.

Comment: Still learning the ins and outs of python so didn't know about the random.shuffle. I just assumed i had to do a standard Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint):

> Return a random integer *N* such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`.

If it's not obvious why this is a problem, let's use a much smaller example:

```
>>> a = ['x', 'y']
>>> len(a)
2
>>> a[0]
'x'
>>> a[1]
'y'
>>> a[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> randint(0, 2)
1
>>> randint(0, 2)
2 # oops
```

---

This is why Python usually uses half-open ranges, where `a <= N < b`, instead of `a <= N <= b`. And why you normally want to use [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) instead of `randint`.

---

Or, even more often, when you find yourself reaching for `randint` or `randrange`, there's a good chance you wanted `shuffle` (which will randomly reorder the whole list in one go), or `choice` (which will pick a value out of a list, without needing to first pick an index), etc., so skim through the docs to see if what you want is already written.

Comment: thanks that fixed problem.  in the future when working with python i will just use shuffle to make it easier.  I feel kind of dumb now that i asked such an obvious question....lul